# Is there a way to list all the tweets by a user?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

Is there any way to list all the tweets by some user using *twitter4j* ?

[`Twitter.get****Timeline()`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html#getHomeTimeline%28%29) returns a List of 20 latest tweets from user's home timeline but what if I want to list all the tweets till date by the user.

Comment: @downvoter why a negative vote ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Paging`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Paging.html) object to fetch more statuses and navigate the timeline, for example:

```
final Paging paging = new Paging();
paging.count(200); // max statuses you can request for this call

List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(userId, paging);
```

To get the next 200 statuses, simply set `paging.maxId` to the `id` of the earliest status you just received and make the call again:

```
paging.maxId(earliestStatusId - 1);
statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(id, paging);
```

And so on...

We subtract one from the `maxId` as it is inclusive and we don't want to fetch the earliest `Status` again.

This approach allows you to fetch statuses in batches of 200 in reverse chronological order. It is one of the ways Twitter recommends to handle timelines, see their guide on [Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines) for more information.

By the way, you can only retrieve around 3k of the user's most recent statuses through this API call, see the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) for more details.

Comment: But if we want to see the first 20 tweets, how are we going to see those, provided we can only retrieve around 3k tweets ?

Comment: If a user has more then 3,200 tweets then it doesn't look like you will be able to retrieve their complete timeline using this approach.